# Add new child to nested state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, nested-object

I would like to create a tree object in React. My initial state has a `name` variable and a children array of objects. Every time when I iterate through my dataset I would like to add an object for my state array of children.

My code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ name: "Tree", children: [{}] });
  const regions = [
    {
      idregion: "region1",
      region_name: "South-Central Asia"
    },
    {
      idregion: "region2",
      region_name: "Balkan Peninsula"
    },
    {
      idregions: "region3",
      region_name: "Northern Africa"
    }
  ];
  
useEffect(() => {
    for (let reg of regions){
      setData((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          children: reg.region_name
        };
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

I tried:

```
setData((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          children: [{ ...prevState }, { name: reg.region_name }]
        };
      });

setData((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          children: [{ ...prevState, name: reg.region_name }]
        };
      });

setData((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          children: [{ ...prevState.children, name: reg.region_name }]
        };
      });
```

My goal would be:

```
{
  name: 'Tree',
  children: [
    { name: 'South-Central Asia' },
    { name: 'Balkan Peninsula' },
    { name: 'Northern Africa' },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Did you try `children: [{ ...prevState.children}, {name: reg.region_name }]`? I don't see it listed, I think this will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({ name: 'Tree', children: [] });
  const regions = [
    {
      idregion: 'region1',
      region_name: 'South-Central Asia',
    },
    {
      idregion: 'region2',
      region_name: 'Balkan Peninsula',
    },
    {
      idregions: 'region3',
      region_name: 'Northern Africa',
    },
  ];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      children: regions.map((r) => ({ name: r.region_name })),
    }));
  }, []);

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You should really never use `setState()` in a loop. As you can see in my example above, I iterate over the `regions` array, create a new array with `.map()` and assign the returned value to the `children` property. Once.

You can use `.map()` to create a new array; for every item in the array, return a new object where the `name` is the `region_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import React from "react";

const regions = [
  {
    idregion: "region1",
    region_name: "South-Central Asia",
  },
  {
    idregion: "region2",
    region_name: "Balkan Peninsula",
  },
  {
    idregions: "region3",
    region_name: "Northern Africa",
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({ name: "Tree", children: [{}] });

  const addRegions = () => {
    setData({ ...data, children: regions });
  };

  console.log(`data`, data);

  // can do it here
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   addRegions();
  // }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addRegions}>Add regions</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array spread operators are spreading the wrong objects:

```js
return {
    ...prevState,
    children: [
        ...prevState.children,     // Copy the previous children over
        { name: reg.region_name }, // Add a new object with name field
    ]
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ name: "Tree", children: [] });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    for (let reg of regions){
      setData((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          children: [...prevState.children, {name: reg.region_name}]
        };
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

But instead of setting the state inside the for loop, you could do some optimization by updating the state like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const children = regions.map(item => ({ name: item.region_name }));
    setData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, children }))
  }, []);
```